# Contact form 7 date placeholder

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a form with a date field (drop_off_date) and i use this code to fix and insert a placeholder:

`<input type="date" name="drop_off_date" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-date" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Drop off date">`

My question is: where i put in this code the date-format:dd/mm/yy and check-in min:today ?

Thanks

Comment: You are better off to use jquery UI datepicker on a text field to get what you want here.  The native date picker from CF7 doesn't work with all browsers anyway.  Add jquery-ui and include a short script, which you can add directly to your contact form on the admin.

Comment: Hi Howard,

Thank you. Any way if I use jquery UI datepicker broke my website, have a conflit with others plugins.

Regards,
José Luís Costa

Comment: Set it so that it only enqueues on the contact form page, or use a different datepicker script.